# SAML AuthnRequest expired before IdP returns to Application with Saml Response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-saml2

I am using spring-security-saml2 for user authentication.

This usually works fine, but the IdP is often slow to come back to the application and I assume that the AuthnRequest has already expired in our application. This expiration-value seems to be 30s.

Which property can I change / or which configuration do I need to make so that the Saml-Response is responding to a still existing AuthRequest?

I currently have the following error in my log:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2023-08-14T13:17:16.976067524Z",
  "logger": "org.opensaml.saml.saml2.assertion.impl.AbstractSubjectConfirmationValidator",
  "level": "WARN",
  "thread": "http-nio-80-exec-7",
  "message": "Valid InResponseTo was not available from the validation context, unable to evaluate SubjectConfirmationData@InResponseTo"
}
```